# Fit all the section titles into the beamer's custom template headline

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using a custom beamer template I found online. There is a bug with the template. The problem is that in the produced pdf I cannot fit all the sections names and some of them are out of the headline space and I cannot see them. What should I look in the .sty in order to find a way to fit all the sections names in the headline. I found out that the following code is responsible for producing the headline for every slide:

```
%% DISABLE THE NAVIGATION SYMBOLS
\defbeamertemplate*{navigation symbols}{CVC}{}
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{CVC}
{
\begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}%
    \ifnum\thepage>1%
        \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt%
    \fi%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

How can I fit all the section titles into the beamer's headline?

Comment: You could use short versions of the section names with `\section{short name}[long name]`. If this does not help, can you make a MWE that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what exactly MWE means?

Comment: I have to apologise for using slang :) Please see [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Short version: it would be nice to have a short but compilable document, that reproduces your problem. This should include the theme you are using.

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58f4afaddbdd207f21caa619

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggestions 1:**

Using a smaller font size, for example `\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4}{6}\selectfont}`

[image]

**Suggestion 2:**

Using short versions of the section names for the navigation bar, for example `\section[Conclusions]{Conclusions \& future work}`

[image]

Comment: The first worked like a charm, the second approach did not work for me.